# Twitter embed timeline 'data-tweet-limit' attribute doesn’t work anymore

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, timeline

the ‘data-tweet-limit’ attribute doesn’t work anymore in my Twitter timeline, it shows all the tweets and don’t take into account the 'data-tweet-limit' attribute (it should display only 6 tweets in this case), can you guys help me? Here’s the code:

```
<a class='twitter-timeline' data-width="350" data-tweet-limit='6' data-chrome='noheader noborders noscrollbar transparent' data-partner='tweetdeck' href='https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/lists/national-parks?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw'>tweet link</a>
```

Comment: did you get any fix for it?

Comment: no, it seems that Twitter doesn't support anymore this attribute

Comment: it is still listed in the docs though